# How to execute a String code in the form of StandardForm?

Tags: bugs, front-end, string-manipulation, boxes, toexpression

How to execute a String code in the form of StandardForm?

I want to get execution results for strings of various forms. For this, I used ToExpression.

```
case1 = ToExpression["(1/2)^3"]
case2 = ToExpression["\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)], \(3\)]\)"]
case3 = ToExpression["(\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \\(3\)]\)"]
```

[image]

As a result of execution, Case 3 did not get the result I wanted. How can I solve it?

---

Here's a GIF showing how 3rd string is created:

[image: gif]

As we can see, once the pair of `"` is added, the size of `()` becomes a bit weird.

Comment: Looks like a bug of front-end. The pair of `()` isn't in a `RowBox` in 3rd case. If the string is obtained with e.g. `ToString[(1/2)^3 // Unevaluated, StandardForm]`, `ToExpression` will handle it properly, though.

Comment: I think it's better to report it to WRI: https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You see this as a bug? I've tested it in v11.3~13.3, but it shows the same symptoms. It's a problem that's been happening since the old version!

Comment: Yes, personally I think it's a bug. And it seems to be broken from the beginning (modern front-end is introduced in _v3_): https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5EBi.png

Comment: Thank you. I submitted this issue to Wolfram.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't say this is a bug. You want to convert an invalid box structure into an expression, and that's why it complains. Whenever you type $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$$ into the notebook, it will be [automatically transformed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHoFy.gif) to the correct box structure containing `RowBox` (making the parentheses large).

Comment: @Domen But once you wrap this correct box structure with a pair of `"`, it becomes incorrect 囧.

Comment: @xzczd, oooh, I see it now, sorry. I retract my previous comment (: However, in my opinion, it should be noted that the bug is in this automatic conversion to the wrong box structure after wrapping in `"`. Perhaps [this gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c81ee.gif) could be included in the question/bug report.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
"(\!\(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(2\)]\)\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\()\), \(3\)]\)" // 
  FrontEnd`ReparseBoxStructurePacket // FrontEndExecute // ToExpression
```

Comment: Oh I even upvoted some of those `ReparseBoxStructurePacket` answers but didn't notice the function is so powerful… Of course +1.

Comment: @xzczd maybe it is, maybe it is not, worked this time :)